# How to attach child fragment directly to the root view of its parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Want to attach an existing Fragment to a DialogFragment.
If I use `<fragment>` node in xml, it is unable to use `newInstance` method to pass arguments.
So I use dynamic way to add the fragment.

```
class StatusDialog : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return FrameLayout(activity!!).apply { id = View.generateViewId() } // have to return a useless node here - -
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(view.id, EmstatusMultiselectLayer.newInstance("abc")).commit()
    }
}
```

But, as you can see this way creates a dummy node. How can I avoid it?
[image]